# yii2 cropper getting 404 when crop image

Tags: php, yii2, framework

https://github.com/budyaga/yii2-cropper использую расширение.

Установил, но при crop image даёт ошибку в console браузера

> http://localhost/st2/frontend/web/uploads/post/
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Как решить задачу?

Comment: Скорее всего система пытается в `http://localhost/st2/frontend/web/uploads/post/` сохранить обрезанный файл, папки нет, падает ошибка. Создайте эту папку и нет проблем.

Comment: Но папка существует!  Я его создал.